# Print Object like console.log (with a lot of information) in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

I need to send an email that contains the `console.log` output of a JS object. Here a code example:

```
let array_multi = [];
array_multi["07:00"] = ["one","two","three"];
array_multi["08:00"] = ["foo","bar","foo"];
array_multi["09:00"] = ["lorem"];
console.log(array_multi);
```

In my console result like this:

[image]

Is there some method to get this output in plain text, or should I write a custom parsing function?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(array_multi)` for text conversion

Comment: `array_multi` should really be an object, not an array!

Comment: If you're doing this manually, the Firefox console lets you right-click on an Object that's been logged to the console, and you can select "Copy object". That will do  the JSON conversion for you, so only JSON-serializable properties are included.

Comment: Is this tagged NodeJS because it is running on NodeJS?

Comment: @Jonas Wilms yes I run inside a node js script and need variable with text for send w/ node mail extesion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search the right method is write a custom function (chrome have once inside dev tools core)
here the solution:

```js
let array_multi = [];
array_multi["07:00"] = ["one","two","three"];
array_multi["08:00"] = ["foo","bar","foo"];
array_multi["09:00"] = ["lorem"];


function print_js_element(elm, show_content = false){
 
 let output_res = "{\n";


 let object_keys = Object.keys(elm);

 object_keys.some(function(key,index) {

  output_res += "\t" + key + ": (" + elm[key].length + ")";

  if(show_content){
   output_res += " " + JSON.stringify(elm[key]);
  }

  output_res += "\n";
 });

 output_res += "\n}";
 return output_res;

}


console.log(print_js_element(array_multi,false));
console.log(print_js_element(array_multi,true));
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), you'll get the complete data, however there are a few downsides:

- Arrays string properties, functions and other data structures get ignored completely (therefore serializing your data as is won't work¹)
- circular references fail to serialize
- There is no way to see inheritance from that

In your case you could do:

```js
let array_multi = {};
array_multi["07:00"] = ["one","two","three"];
array_multi["08:00"] = ["foo","bar","foo"];
array_multi["09:00"] = ["lorem"];

// logs as object
console.log(array_multi);
console.log(typeof array_multi);

// parse and convert to string
console.log(JSON.stringify(array_multi)); 
console.log(typeof JSON.stringify(array_multi));
```

---

In Node.js you've got another option, which is [util.format](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args), which will return the same content as a string that you can see in the Node.js console. While it does give you a great insight into the different datatypes and relationships, it cannot show you the same infinite tree that an interactive console is able to show, so it will only show you a small part of the big picture.

---

¹: Your `array_multi` should actually be an object, not an array, as arrays should only have numeric keys.

Comment: Why the downvote? I precisely answers the OP's question.

Comment: I am using the OP's data while precising that it should be an object instead of an array

Comment: Yes yes sorry, I saw that. (I didn't downvote.) I think this is probably the best the OP can do, but it should be noted that not all object graphs can be serialized as JSON. (Well a custom serializer would be the next step I guess.)

Answer (score -1):

Covert this array into an object first:

```js
let array_multi = [];
array_multi["07:00"] = ["one","two","three"];
array_multi["08:00"] = ["foo","bar","foo"];
array_multi["09:00"] = ["lorem"];

let arrObj = {...array_multi};

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrObj));
```